# I am struggling in calculationg Fourier transform?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I need to find the Fourier transformation of $f(x)=\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ by two different methods. one is using the property of Fourier transformation, another is computing the integral by definition.

For method 1 of using the property of Fourier transformation:

Since I already know the Fourier transformation of $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is $\widehat g(\epsilon)=\pi e^{-\epsilon}$ and $\widehat{g(x)g(x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\widehat g *\widehat g(\epsilon)$. I can write $f=g(x)g(x)x.$ So I first compute $\widehat{g(x)g(x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\widehat g *\widehat g(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_y\widehat g(\epsilon -y)\widehat g(y)dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\pi^2\int_ye^{-\epsilon +y}e^{-y}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\pi^2\int_ye^{-\epsilon }dy$

But I don't know how to calculate $\int_ye^{-\epsilon }dy$? Does $y$ go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? I feel so confused.

Can anyone help me? Please. Thanks so much!

Comment: $y$ should cover the entire domain, which I'm guessing in this case is just the reals. However, that presents an issue with the convergence of the integral you have.

Comment: @Brandon Does that mean that my using $f=g(x)g(x)x$ is not appropriate in using method 1. I have to find different decomposition of $f$? Thanks so much! It is so confusing.:)

Comment: Your decomposition of $f$ is fine.  However, $\widehat{g}(\epsilon)=\pi e^{-|\epsilon|}$.  That should fix your convergence issue.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks so much! That solves it! I got something like when $\epsilon>0$, $f(\epsilon)=\frac{\pi}{2}(\epsilon +1)e^{-\epsilon}$. when $\epsilon<0$, $f(\epsilon)=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\epsilon)e^{\epsilon}$. Does that make sense in $R$?

Comment: Your powers of $e$ look good, but you might double check your $(\epsilon+1)$ and $(1-\epsilon)$ terms.  I got $(1+\epsilon)e^\epsilon$ for $\epsilon<0$ and $(1-\epsilon)e^{-\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon>0$ (with the constants still multiplied outfront).